# Laravel 5 weird URL Routing

Tags: url, routes, laravel-5

I'm working on a Laravel 5 project and I'm using some ajax call. But something weird is happening. I have this error. `404 Not Found`

```
http://localhost/qms/public/crm/api/questions/childcount?colheader=guidedogs_001
```

It's an ajax call. My route is

```
Route::get('api/questions/childcount', 'QuestionController@apiQuestionChildCount');
```

Now, I know that the url in the error page appends the `crm` after the `public` so now I will update my route to

```
Route::get('crm/api/questions/childcount', 'QuestionController@apiQuestionChildCount');
```

Then when I try again I still the `404 Not Found` error with the url being

```
http://localhost/qms/public/crm/crm/api/questions/childcount?colheader=guidedogs_001
```

It's appending another `crm`

What could be the problem? Sometimes it works and now its not. I am calling the ajax request in the page `http://localhost/qms/public/crm/create`

Comment: How are you writing the link in the javascript.Because from your question, I suspect it works in some pages but not on others

Comment: It works now, I figured it out, on my javascript it's api/questions/childcount and my route needs to be crm/api/questions/childcount. Dunno what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

It works now, I figured it out, on my javascript it's `api/questions/childcount` and my route needs to be `crm/api/questions/childcount`. Dunno what's happening.